# Ruby DateTime format: Unable to get 1st, 5th etc

Tags: ruby, activesupport

How do I get ruby date format to have th, st, rd etc? For example today is August 5th. I know this question has been asked before and I have followed the solutions provided in those answers but they do not appear to work for me.

I have tried the following three ways:

```
time = DateTime.now
time.strftime("%A, %B #{time.day.ordinalize} %Y")

=> 2016-08-05T10:29:52-04:00

time = Time.now()
time.strftime("#{time.day.ordinalize} %B %Y")

=> 2016-08-05 10:29:52 -0400

time = Time.new
day = time.strftime("%d")
day.ordinalize

=>  NoMethodError:
   undefined method `ordinalize' for "05":String
```

I have included the following in my spec_helper.rb file:

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/integer/inflections'
```

I am using ruby 2.3.0p0, active support gem is version 4.2.6.

Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: can you try the following commands? `gem install activesupport`
then `irb` then
`irb> require 'rubygems'`
#=>  true
`irb> require 'activesupport'`
#=>  true
`irb> 3.ordinalize`
#=>  "3rd"

Answer (score 0):

I tested what your code in rails console, and for me it's working.

Another way to do this is also using the ordinalize method from ActiveSupport::Inflector or to_formatted_s (both methods are also present in this post  https://stackoverflow.com/a/14665335/4340756 ):

`:018 > time = Time.now()
 => 2016-08-05 17:57:26 +0300 
 :019 > ActiveSupport::Inflector.ordinalize(time.day)
 => "5th"
:022 > time.to_formatted_s(:long_ordinal) 
 => "August 5th, 2016 17:59"`

Where did you tested this code and what version of rails do you have?

Comment: Hi Ovidiu, I am not actually using rails, I am using rspec/capybara as an integration test tool. Is the ordinalize method a rails method? I thought it was ruby method.

Comment: I presumed that you are using rails because `ordinalize` method comes from ActiveSupport::Inflector. ActiveSupport it's a ruby gem, but it's by default included in Rails [https://rubygems.org/gems/activesupport/versions/5.0.0]. Have you tried what  @Tall Paul commented on the initial question?